# How can't this equation be solved?

Tags: equation-solving

```
Solve[{x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1, {x + c, y} . {x - c, y} == 0, a > 0, 
  b > 0, c > 0}, {x, y}]
```

The software keeps prompting for running, but cannot calculate the result. Why?

Comment: It gives a result almost instantly on Mathematica 13.2.1.0 but it's hugely complicated [so I've put it on pastebin here](https://pastebin.com/514aa4jq)

Comment: `sol = Solve[{x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1, {x + c, y} . {x - c, y} == 0, 
   c > a > 0, c > b > 0}, {x, y}, Reals]`

Comment: @csn899 This is an amplication and not a contradiction of cvgmt's comment's. I also am using Mathematica 13.2.1. Both Solve and Reduce complete quickly (1.4 seconds in Complex mode in Reduce on my ancient machine from 2011}. The ByteCount of the result is 60768 bytes. `Timing[ByteCount[
  sol = ToRadicals[
    Reduce[{x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1, {x + c, y} . {x - c, y} == 0, 
      c > a > 0, c > b > 0}, {x, y}, Cubics -> True, 
     Quartics -> True]]]]` So what version of Mathematica are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)"  *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Assuming[{a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}, 
 Solve[{x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1, {x + c, y} . {x - c, y} == 0}, {x, y}] // 
  FullSimplify]
```

[image]

If you also restrict x and y to reals,

```
Assuming[{a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, Element[{x, y}, Reals]}, 
 Solve[{x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1, {x + c, y} . {x - c, y} == 0}, {x, y}] // 
  FullSimplify]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can help Mathmatica solve the equations as follows:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, x, y, X, Y, X2, Y2];
x = a*X; y = b*Y;
equs = Simplify[{x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1, {x+c, y}.{x-c, y} == 0}];
Solve[ equs/. {X^2 -> X2, Y^2 -> Y2}, {X2, Y2}] //Simplify //InputForm
(* {{X2 -> (b^2 + c^2)/(a^2 + b^2), Y2 -> (-a^2 + c^2)/(a^2 + b^2)}} *)
```

where `X2 == (x/a)^2, Y2 == (y/b)^2`.

You asked

> The software keeps prompting for running, but cannot calculate the result. Why?

I can not answer that question because it involves detailed knowledge
of the actual software version of Mathematica and algorithms used by
Mathematica. However, if you just want to get a useful solution to
your equations, then I have given that to you using simple replacements
before and after the `Solve[]`.